# How does the Sword of The Thunder God get stopped by a Kunai?

Tags: naruto

I used to watch Naruto a long time ago and I remember there being a filler anime about people using lightning techniques..

One thing I remember specifically was that one of the ninjas was using a lightning weapon that was supposed to be able to cut through anything including Chakra...

The problem was that one of the Ninjas from Hidden Leaf if I remember correctly was fighting them and stopping the blade with a regular Kunai...

How does that work?  If the lightning weapon can cut through anything including Chakra why would a regular kunai stop it?

After a quick research the weapon is the Sword of the Thunder God... as stated on Naruto Wikia: [Sword of the Thunder God - Narutopedia, the Naruto Encyclopedia Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_the_Thunder_God)

> As shown in Aoi's fight with Naruto Uzumaki and Sasuke Uchiha, the
>   blade was shown to not only be able to easily cut through any solid
>   object, but also through chakra-based substances as well.

After rewatching the episodes again the person using the sword swung at a ninja then a couple of kunais is seen to drop to the floor blocking the attack...

The Kunais are seen to be intact... So if this sword can cut through anything why was his attack stopped by them?

Comment: is the filler related before Captain Asuma's death?

Comment: In the normal naruto or in the shippuuden ? all I could think of was the Chakra Scalpel technique used to for example cut chakra cords. this also could be extended to weapons

Comment: This is the normal Naruto

Comment: Found it by searching online... The Sword of the Thunder God... I remember a Kunai stopping it if I recall correctly.  Added to the original question might edit it also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fillers are parts of the series that are designed to give the manga time to get a larger distance from the anime.

Generally, less experienced (and less paid) writers do these fillers, not the original mangaka.

This results in inconsistencies with the general storyline, and sometimes, even inside the episodes themselves (due to the writer's lesser experience).

Now I haven't checked the credits for that specific episode, to see who was the script writer for it, but my educated guess is that this is the case. A plot hole, and nothing more.

Comment: So essentially plot Kunai lol....